# Sorting list of dictionary in case of key doesn't exist

Tags: python, sorting

I have list of dictionary and want to sort by price in ascending order.
But few dictionary objects have no price key available to sort. 
I want to move those object to end of the list.

I have tried below code

`sorted(listObj, key=partial(sort_func, ['price']))`

```
def sort_func(sort_by, listObj):
    fields = []
    for key in sort_by:
        if key in listObj:
            fields.append(listObj[key])
    return fields
```

And I want to sort below kind of data:

```
data = [
        {
           u'errorCode': u'500',
           u'errorMsg': u'Pfffbt. server down.',
        },
        {
           u'errorCode': u'500',
           u'errorMsg': u'Pfffbt. server down.',
        },
        { 
            u'Name': u'United Kingdon',
            u'price': 5222.0,
        },
        {
            u'price': 5237.0,
            u'Name': u'US',
        },
        {
            u'Name': u'General',
            u'price': 5283.0,
        }
    ]
```

while sorting these data using price ascending order, **`5222.0`** price should come first instead of **`errorcode`** object.

Note: I don't want to use lambda function because it could have **multiple keys with some condition to sort using `sort_func` So I've to use `sort_func` anyhow.**

I found one solution but it is not reliable.

```
def sort_func(sort_by, listObj):
    fields = []
    for key in sort_by:
        if key in listObj:
            fields.append(listObj[key])
        else:
            fields.append(99999999999999999999999999) # infinity number
    return fields
```

Any other suggestion with using `sort_func`?

Comment: `sorted(data, key=lambda x:x.get("price", 0))` I haven't ran it, but something close to this should get you a sorted list, Here I am assuming that if the price doesn't exist, then take `0` as default value, you may try with `-1` as well.

Comment: Multiple conditions I am checking in sort_func to sort the data so I have to use it anyhow. and also it could have sort by multiple keys not only 'price'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a 'missing_key' counter and increment it for each missing key. return a tuple of `(missing_keys, fields)` and they'll get sorted at the end with the most missing keys going last.

```
def sort_func(sort_by, listObj):
    missing_keys = 0
    fields = []
    for key in sort_by:
        if key in listObj:
            fields.append(listObj[key])
        else:
            missing_keys += 1
    return missing_keys, fields
```

**edit: request for detailed explanation**

tuples(and lists) sort as follows: compare first elements.  If first elements **aren't** equal, use that comparison, else compare 2nd elements etc....  an empty tuple/list is always less than one with elements. so:

```
lst = [
    (), (10,), (1, []), (2, [10, 11]), (2, [100]), (0, [10, 9, 8]), (0, [11]), (1, [1, 1, 2])
]
print(sorted(lst))
```

prints:

```
[
    (),
    (0, [10, 9, 8]),
    (0, [11]),
    (1, []),
    (1, [1, 1, 2]),
    (2, [10, 11]),
    (2, [100]),
    (10,)
]
```

This `sort_func` returns a tuple. If the first element (missing_keys) is equal, it's evaluated by the next element (fields). But it first sorts by the number of missing keys.

Comment: Can you give some explanation how missing_keys affected?

Comment: If that explanation is not clear, please ask more questions in these comments.

Comment: I just want to understand how it worked by returning missing key

Comment: this `sort_func` first sorts by the number of keys not in the data, and then by the list of fields.  so the most missing keys sorts highest. the data with all the fields sort lowest.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use `lambda`, you can try this:

```
new_data = sorted([i for i in data if "price" in i], reverse=True)+[i for i in data if "errorCode" in i]
```

Output:

```
[{u'price': 5222.0, u'Name': u'United Kingdon'}, {u'price': 5237.0, u'Name': u'US'}, {u'price': 5283.0, u'Name': u'General'}, {u'errorCode': u'500', u'errorMsg': u'Pfffbt. server down.'}, {u'errorCode': u'500', u'errorMsg': u'Pfffbt. server down.'}]
```

Comment: Multiple conditions I am checking in `sort_func` to sort the data so I have to use it anyhow. and also it could have sort by multiple keys not only 'price'.